# "Delete information" if its value is empty Firestore Swift

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, swiftui

I have this code to get information from Firestore:

```
struct Spty: Identifiable{
    var id: String
    var spty: String

    var r: NSNumber
    var g: NSNumber
    var b: NSNumber

}

class SptyViewModel: NSObject, ObservableObject{
    @Published var specialities = [Spty]()
    @Published var search = ""
    func fetchData(){
        let db = Firestore.firestore()
        db.collection("specialities").addSnapshotListener { (querySnapshot, error) in
            guard let documents = querySnapshot else {return }
            self.specialities = documents.documents.compactMap { (doc) -> Spty? in
               let id = doc.documentID
                let spty = doc.get("spty") as? String ?? ""
                let r = doc.get("r") as?  NSNumber ?? 0
                let g = doc.get("g") as?  NSNumber ?? 0
                let b = doc.get("b") as?  NSNumber ?? 0
                
                return Spty(id: id, spty: spty, r: r , g: g , b: b )
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I use `@StateObject` to refer to it and `ForEach` to display the data.

If, in Firestore, I create a document in the collection, but don't create the fields listed above (spty, r, g, b) I'll get a black rectangle (as the code above).

What I want is: if there is not the right field (for example, spty), it will be forgotten (instead of showing the black rectangle, e.g: if I have 4 correct documents and just add a new one without the correct fields, ill get only the 4 correct, instead of 5 ).

I know it has something to do with as? String ?? `""`, I just do not know what

Comment: Have you tried using Firestore's Codable support to perform the mapping? Makes your code easier to read and solves most (if not all) of your mapping issues. See https://peterfriese.dev/swiftui-firebase-codable/ for details

Comment: Hey @PeterFriese, actually just recently asked a question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65428943/errors-after-changing-nsnumber-to-int-double) about this. Im having problems changing `NSNumber` to `Int/Double` so I can properly use `Codable`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is pretty simple:

```
          let id = doc.documentID
            if  let spty = doc.get("spty") as? String,
            let r = doc.get("r") as?  NSNumber,
            let g = doc.get("g") as?  NSNumber,
            let b = doc.get("b") as?  NSNumber{
            
            return Spty(id: id, spty: spty, r: r , g: g , b: b )
            }
            else{
                return nil
            }
```

added a if statement